# How to call a stored procedure that returns a list<int> using .net core entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am migrating a `.Net Framework` project to `.Net Core`. In my `.Net Framework` code I call a stored procedure and it returns a `list<int>` in a `datatable`:

```
 DataTable dt = new DLDistinctWarehousePackingOperation().CreatePacking(packingId, userId, 
 previousOrderId, totalAwaitingOrdersAllowed);
        List<int> items = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            items.Add(int.Parse(dr["orderid"].ToString()));
        }
        return items;
```

This is the `.Net Core` code I have come up with until now:

```
List<int> items = dbContext.FromSql("CreatePacking")
            .Select(t => new List<int> { t.OrderId.Value })
            .ToList();
```

But it doesn't work. The problem is that an object needs to follow dbContext  - like this dbContext.MyObject.FromSql - but in this case it should just be a List of ints - the stored procedure is not connected to any specific object. And how can I return a `List<int>`? or perhaps it has to be converted into a class? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: `But it doesn't work.` How **specifically** does it not work?

Comment: `List<int> items = _context.MyObject.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.CreatePacking").ToList().SelectMany(t => new List<int> { t.OrderId}).ToList();`

Comment: You can use [this approach](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1862#issuecomment-451671168) to define a query type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the stored procedure name is `CreatePacking`, define the property in your DbContext. For example

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    ...............
    
    [NotMapped]
    public DbSet<CreatePackingResult> CreatePackingResult { get; set; }
    
    ...............
    ...............
}
```

And then define the result class

```
 public class CreatePackingResult
 {
      public int OrderId { get; set;}
 }
```

Finally

```
 List<int> items = dbContext.CreatePackingResult.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE [dbo].[CreatePacking]")
                  .Select(t => t.OrderId)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Epic Chen - thanks for the reply - please take a look at the image I have attached to my question - the debug error message is "invalid object name 'createpackingresult' - do you know what the issue is ?

I did add this:
     public class CreatePackingResult
     {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
    }
as well as this line to ApplicationCoreDbContext:
public DbSet<CreatePackingResult> CreatePackingResult { get; set; }

Comment: Hi @Nick Developer, I notice that there are something i forget to add at FromSqlRaw, I have updated answer again. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

Comment: Brilliant!  I've been looking for this answer for about 10 business hours!  And not only did you answer it, but you laid it out in an understandable and useful example!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple demo,you can check it.

Simple class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudent
     -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @Name VARCHAR(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
     -- Insert statements for procedure here
     SELECT * FROM Student WHERE [Name] = @Name
    END
    GO
```

Get item:

```
 var user = "xx"
 List<int> items = _context.Student.FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE dbo.GetStudent{user}").ToList().SelectMany(t => new List<int> { t.Id }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure doesn't really produces a list of numbers,
it returns a table with one column of integer.

So you should get back an object with one integer property.